# Problem with my graphic card

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 3d, hardware-acceleration

I've recently installed Ubuntu `12.04`. However I'm having some problems with the graphic drivers.

My graphic card is GeForce 7150m / nForce 630. I've installed a lot of updates, however I can only run Ubuntu in 2D and most applications are very slow(e.g. google earth, or pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>).

Does anyone has any idea how I can solve this problem? I'd be very grateful.
Thanks.
Daniel.

Comment: Do you only have one graphic card? Or have more? You say you installed updates, but what updates? You need to install your graphic card drivers, so you can get acess to the 3d capability of your card.

Comment: I only have one graphic card. I installed updates trough the command
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nvidia
It hasn't worked tho...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instalation through PPAm just purge your previus install and reinstall again

Run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvidia-vdpau/ppa
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys CEC06767
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia
```

If that doesn't work you can try  the propietary drivers from Nvidia, you can try this:

1. Go to http://nvidia.com and download the driver to a known directory (`~/Downloads`, for example)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to switch to another Virtual Terminal and login with your User/Password
3. Run `sudo service lightdm stop` (or Nvidia installer will not run, because there's an active X session)
4. Run `cd ~/Downloads && sudo chmod +x ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-295.33.run` (if that's the version you have downloaded, to make the installer executable)
5. Run `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-295.33.run` and press "OK" to all installer questions (default options)
6. As the installer finishes, run `sudo reboot now` to reboot the machine.
7. At lightdm, login to Unity 3D and verify if there was any change or improvement.

Also:

- Make sure you are not running nouveau. You can check if nouveau is loaded by running `lsmod | grep -i nouveau`. It should display no results.
- Make sure your currently loaded NVidia kernel module is the same version as the installed drivers.
- You can check that Nvidia Kernel module is is loaded with `lsmod | grep -i nv`. If you installed Nvidia drivers from the proprietary/binary installer from NVidia website/FTP it should output "nvidia".
- If you have NVidia installed from Ubuntu repos (pakage `nvidia-current`) it should output nvidiafb.
- To check the Kernel module version, use `modinfo nvidia` or `modinfo nvidiafb`. It should output "version:  along with other module details.

This version should match the drivers you installed.

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/982485)

Comment: It didn't work. And I can't download the drivers because they're only available for windows...

Comment: I don't know which site you went to, but Nvidia has drivers for Linux: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Comment: Actually if you pick nForce series 6: nforce 630i / GeForce 7150m it only has drivers for windows... :'|